# Sqoop Hive table import, Table dataType doesn't match with database

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

Using Sqoop to import data from oracle to hive, its working fine but it create table in hive with only 2 dataTypes String and Double. I want to use timeStamp as datatype for some columns.
How can I do it.

```
bin/sqoop import --table TEST_TABLE --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:orcl --username USER1 -password password -hive-import --hive-home /user/lib/Hive/
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to above answers we may also have to observe when the error is coming, e.g.

In my case I had two types of data columns that caused error: json and binary

**for json column** the error came while a Java Class was executing, at the very beginning of the import process :

```
/04/19 09:37:58 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type
```

**for binary column**, error was thrown while importing into the hive tables (after data is imported and put into HDFS files)

```
16/04/19 09:51:22 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column featured_binary
```

> To get rid of these two errors, I had to provide the following options

```
--map-column-java column1_json=String,column2_json=String,featured_binary=String --map-column-hive column1_json=STRING,column2_json=STRING,featured_binary=STRING
```

In summary, we may have to provide the

```
--map-column-java
```

or

```
--map-column-hive
```

depending upon the failure.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the parameter `--map-column-hive` to override default mapping. This parameter expects a comma-separated list of key-value pairs separated by **=** to specify which column should be matched to which type in Hive.

```
sqoop import \
  ...
  --hive-import \
  --map-column-hive id=STRING,price=DECIMAL
```

Answer (score 5):

A new feature was added with sqoop-2103/sqoop 1.4.5 that lets you call out the decimal precision with the map-column-hive parameter.  Example:

```
--map-column-hive 'TESTDOLLAR_AMT=DECIMAL(20%2C2)'
```

This syntax would define the field as a `DECIMAL(20,2)`.  The `%2C` is used as a comma and the parameter needs to be in single quotes if submitting from the bash shell.

I tried using Decimal with no modification and I got a `Decimal(10,0)` as a default.

Comment: I tried it your way `(20%C2)` but that results in an error (complains about `%`) on the Hive import phase. If you try just `DECIMAL(20)`, then the `0` is filled in automatically and it works.

Comment: "define Decimal(n,p) data type in map-column-hive option"  is is available in version 1.4.7